# Cannot read i2c device properly

Tags: qt, embedded, embedded-linux, ioctl, i2c

I am trying to write an embedded qt application that reads the specific i2c rtc device. Here is my code to init i2c:

```
int addr = 0x68;        // The I2C address of the RTC

sprintf(filename,I2C_FILE_NAME);
if ((file = open(filename,O_RDWR)) < 0)
{
    qDebug()<<"Failed to open the bus.";
    return;
}

if (ioctl(file,I2C_SLAVE_FORCE,addr) < 0)
{
    qDebug()<<"Failed to acquire bus access and/or talk to slave.\n";
    return;
}
```

To read from device:

```
unsigned char addr = 0x68;
unsigned char reg = 0x00;
unsigned char inbuf[2], outbuf;

struct i2c_rdwr_ioctl_data packets;
struct i2c_msg messages[2];

/*
* In order to read a register, we first do a "dummy write" by writing
* 0 bytes to the register we want to read from.  This is similar to
* the packet in set_i2c_register, except it's 1 byte rather than 2.
*/
outbuf = reg;
messages[0].addr  = addr;
messages[0].flags = 0;
messages[0].len   = sizeof(outbuf);
messages[0].buf   = &outbuf;
/* The data will get returned in this structure */
messages[1].addr  = addr;
messages[1].flags = I2C_M_RD/* | I2C_M_NOSTART*/;
messages[1].len   = 2;
messages[1].buf   = inbuf;
/* Send the request to the kernel and get the result back */
packets.msgs      = messages;
packets.nmsgs     = 2;
if(ioctl(file, I2C_RDWR, &packets) < 0)
{
    qDebug()<<"Unable to send data";
    return;
}
qDebug() << inbuf[0];
```

What I am trying to do is just read rtc device's register that holds the "seconds". What I get is some numbers but those numbers looks good at first but there is some weird incrementation. Like, `55,56,56,57` then it jumps to `64`? then it is going up to `89` then `0`? I don't know why this happens or what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Wow, using qDebug() instead of printf() in a non-qt code for printing.... That is a really weird idea. :-)

Comment: Which i2c device is this?

Comment: it is a RTC, ds1337. here it's datasheet http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1337-DS1337C.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the register doesn't hold a simple count for the number of seconds. The upper bits hold tens of seconds and the lower bits hold unit seconds.

You can obtain tens of seconds with `(inbuf[0] >> 4) & 0x7;` and unit seconds with `inbuf[0] & 0xf`.

Instead of trying to print seconds with `qDebug() << inbuf[0];`, use something like:

```
qDebug() << (10 * ((inbuf[0] >> 4) & 0x7) + (inbuf[0] & 0xf));
```

Comment: How do you know this without knowing the device?

Comment: @MartinJames: the OP did not actually publish the device, so I am not sure what manual you would read then... Perhaps the OP and Krueger had a previous discussion, so the context was known, but for new people like me, it is not. That is why asking for clarification...

Comment: the device is a RTC, ds1337. here it's datasheet datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1337-DS1337C.pdf

Comment: it works but i dont understand how can you understand without knowing the device ? Are all RTC Devices have the same standards ?

Comment: Using binary-coded decimal for clock values isn't a standard, but it's also not unusual. If you convert the example counts in the question to hexadecimal representations, the pattern is easy to see.